Find the last word
Every word below is in the word search... Or is it?!?! Find the last word.

Asgard
frost
tomcat
exist
roots
wrong
oxlip
ruth
depart
fadge
obey
urds
newsmen
disaster
resize
oscars
thulium
oncost
nobody
Ecuador
...?


Text version:
NDISASSDRW
OBEYOTETTR
HUELOORNAO
OATOAEXDSN
SDRRZMDLSF
COTIOEOSIR
ARRTXCAWWO
REUITOMCAS
RHSLIUMNGT
ASGARDORDE


The last word is

TESTAMENT!

This isn't any normal crossword...

In fact, once a word is placed, all its letters are replaced by the next letter in the alphabet for new words to be found. This is hinted at in the list of words, as if you look at the first letters, they say

 ‘AFTER WORD FOUND ROT ONE’

Telling us to apply Rot 1 on the words after finding them. The words can then be found as follows:



(Hopefully that isn't too confusing - see @Flourine's answer for a better step by step of the words)

Now

If we take the letters that aren't used we see they spell

NOT THE LASMT WORD

This clearly says 'NOT THE LAST WORD'... but there is an M in the middle which should not be there. So the last word should use the M cell to fill in the grid so it makes sense.

By removing all the clutter and just keeping the grid after all the letters are updated we can see the word 'TESTAMENT' in the middle row to use the M!




@Fluorine ah yep that makes more sense than just randomly replacing letters, changed the final answer by one letter to make it make sense

I have a feeling you're not quite at the end. My reading of this puzzle was that rot13(lbh nhtzrag RIREL yrggre ol 1 bapr lbh svaq n jbeq, abg whfg gur pebffbire yrggref. V nyfb guvax gur zrffntr ABG GUR YNFG JBEQ vf n erq ureevat naq jung lbh ner cebonoyl zrnag gb qb vf ybbx ng gur shyyl nhtzragrq tevq gb svaq fbzr gurzngvp jbeq va gur raq fgngr bs gur tevq.) That might be worth a look...

@Stiv ah I just realised what the final word is. Doing what you said made it much easier to see, although either method provides the same result. Wasn't a red herring by the looks of it, think I still have the right idea to use the M, but I'll update the answer and you'll see what I mean
Will have to see if that is the final answer the OP intended, but that makes much more sense, thanks for the tip, made that so much more obvious!

Well done, finding the last word. I have put a big hint hidden in the words to show the correct way to solve this word-search. Was expecting you would need this hint, before finding all the words... people here on PSE keep surprising me :)
If you find this hint as well, the green tick is yours!

@Lezzup Was in such a rush to find all the words, missed that completely! Will edit it in now :)

You've got it! :)

I know I am second but since for this puzzle the answer can be hard to read on a single grid, I figured another view, step by step, could be helpful. Of course this is not intended to replace the actual answer by Beastly Gerbil.

 


Very helpful, and much clearer than my mess of a grid!

indeed a nice addition and a good answer as well. The green tick is for Beastly Gerbil, but I have the honor to make this a 'Nice answer' badge. Congrats on 10 bronze badges! :)
